# "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer" error

Tags: c++, linux

I wrote a program in Linux in Python and C++, which I launch with a script `./run.sh`. I am running into a strange phenomenon like this:

At first, I compiled my files and then execute ./run.sh --> everything is fine

- I re-run ./run.sh --> error
- If I re-compile and re-run --> it is ok.

Thus, to not generate the error, I have to re-compile the code before running it.

The error is: `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`

My code is below:

```
float percentage = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < N_cubes; i++) {
    float newPercentage = i * 100.0/N_cubes;

    if ((newPercentage - percentage) >= 10.0) {
        std::cout
            << "Computing Z_CFIE_near chunk. "
            << std::floor(newPercentage)
            <<  " % completed."
            << endl;
        flush(std::cout);
        percentage = newPercentage;
    }

    // computing the local arrays
    int N_RWG_test, N_RWG_src, N_neighbors, N_nodes, S;

    blitz::Array<int, 1> test_RWGsNumbers, src_RWGsNumbers;
    blitz::Array<int, 1> neighbors_cubes;
    blitz::Array<int, 2> localTestSrcRWGNumber_signedTriangles, localTestSrcRWGNumber_nodes;
    blitz::Array<double, 2> nodesCoord;
    blitz::Array<double, 1> rCubeCenter(3);

    compute_cube_local_arrays(
        N_RWG_test,
        N_RWG_src,
        N_neighbors,
        N_nodes,
        S,
        test_RWGsNumbers,
        src_RWGsNumbers,
        neighbors_cubes,
        localTestSrcRWGNumber_signedTriangles,
        localTestSrcRWGNumber_nodes,
        nodesCoord,
        rCubeCenter,
        allCubeIntArrays(i),
        allCubeDoubleArrays(i));

    // computing the Z_CFIE
    blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 2> Z_CFIE_J(N_RWG_test, N_RWG_src);
    blitz::Array<std::complex<float>, 1> Z_CFIE_J_linear(N_RWG_test * N_RWG_src);
}
```

From my understanding, this error is caused because `Z_CFIE_J` and `Z_CFIE_J_linear` could not be freed after few loops (the local variables will be freed after each loop).

Could you please give me some idea to solve this problem?

Comment: may be this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199729/how-to-solve-munmap-chunk-invalid-pointer-error-in-c?rq=1

Comment: the strange thing is that the error did not occur when I first run the code (right after compiling). It just happen if I re-run it without recompiling. Thank you for your suggestion Sibrajas